# Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]

Tags: java, spring, testing

I tried to test my classes:

```
@Configuration
public class PluginConfig {
   @Bean
   public Supplier messageSupplier(){
      return () -> "plugin";
   }


@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryEntity, Long> {}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfigurationde
public class PluginConfigTest {

@Autowired
private CountryRepository repository;

@Test
public void nullable() {
    assertNotNull(repository);
}
```

And i got an exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.

```
at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:143)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAllMergedAnnotations(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:126)
    ... 23 more

Comment: Facing the same issue, have you got any solution?

Comment: Nope. I don't have solution.

Comment: This question is already answered here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013452/could-not-load-testcontextbootstrapper-spring-unit-testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013452/could-not-load-testcontextbootstrapper-spring-unit-testing)

Comment: Seems you have a typo in @ContextConfigurationde.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem. There are problems with the dependencies in the pom.xml file (if you are using Maven). There could be many reasons for that: a conflict in versions, or conflict declaring the same dependency twice: in the current pom.xml and also in the parent pom.xml, like using different versions.

Comment: I faced the same issue and this answer solved my problem. Specially check version compatibility of spring framework dependencies and junit dependency.